# Buying the OS with creditcard

Tags: release-loki

I'd like to buy an iso, but I don't want to use a creditcard, prefer to use PayPal. How to go about that?

Comment: Maybe you will be donate to Patreon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download it as free of charge (like @ourfor's said), then head to [this](https://elementary.io/get-involved#funding), where you can choose PayPal as your payment. Also refer to @AlphAShOOt's answer, you can become a Patron too to support elementary OS.

In my experience, I did download it as free and pay using PayPal.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can download it free of charge